# complexity problem on PHP Array key pairs value transfer

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays. array1 and array2 are identical, except array2's subarrays don't have key 'key3' and the order of subarray is not matched.

```
$array1=array(
    0=>array(
        'type'=>'1'
        'id'=>'1'
        'key3'=>'abc'
        )
    1=>array(
        'type'=>'1'
        'id'=>'2'
        'key3'=>'def'
        )
    3=>array(
        'type'=>'2'
        'id'=>'1'
        'key3'=>'ghi'
        )
    ...
)
$array2=array(
    0=>array(
        'type'=>'1'
        'id'=>'1'
        )
    1=>array(
        'type'=>'2'
        'id'=>'1'
        )
    ...
)
```

the task is simply put the key3 and its value to array2's corresponding subarray.

I can only think of several levels of foreach looping to achieve the task, which would be very costly

Are there any ways that can do the tasks simpler and faster?

Comment: Is efficiency a visible issue in your current situation? or did you just presume that your implementation would be inefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// build a hash table of id/type => key3 for fast access
$index = array();
foreach ($array1 as $data) {
    $index[$data['id'].'/'.$data['type']] = $data['key3'];
}

// use that hash table
foreach ($array2 as &$data) {
    $data['key3'] = $index[$data['id'].'/'.$data['type']];
}
// never forget to unset the variable if iterating by reference
unset($data);
```

Why this is fast: You have only two loops with N iterations, where N delimits the number of elements, so that is of complexity `O(N)`. The hash access is considered `O(1)`. So whole complexity is linear. Nested loop iteration would be `O(N^2)`.